# Can't figure out why I am getting unititalized constants error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a comment to specific post and when I click on comment, I get uninitialized constant Squeals.. I do have the routes

## SQUEAL Models

```
class Squeal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

## comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to:commentable, polymorphic:true
end
```

## /squeal/comments_controller.rb

```
class Squeals::CommentsController <CommentsController
  before_action :set_commentable

  private
  def set_commentable
    @commentable = Squeal.find(params[:squeal_id])
  end

end
```

## comments Controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action:authenticate_user!

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new comment_params
    @user.user = current_user
    comment.save
    redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Your comment was posted"
  end

  private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

## ROUTES

```
resources :squeals do
  resources :comments, module: :squeals
end
```

## squeal/show.html.erb

Comment: Is it possible for us get a look at the exact error log output?

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
class Squeals::CommentsController <CommentsController
```

you are nesting the `CommentsController` inside the `Squeals` class, which you haven't defined anywhere.

If you instead did this, it would work if you saved the file at `app/controllers/squeals/comments_controller.rb` (this is probably necessary because of the way Rails autoloads code)

```
class Squeals
  class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    ...
  end
end
```

The one-liner syntax for making a nested class requires that the parent already exist.

Comment: I will delete the answer later. Maybe try putting class squeals definition in config/initializers

Comment: i am not going to use the polymorphic comments ... i did this on comments controller instead of what i commented out...

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
comment.save to @comment.save
```

OR try to install pry gem in Gemfile

```
gem 'pry'
```

and debug the code.

Answer (score 1):

hi guys i no longer did the polymorphic comments i solve it by doing the following:

```
def create
@post = Squeal.find(params[:squeal_id])
@comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
if @comment.save
redirect_to @post
else
flash.now[:danger] = "error"
end
end
```

## in my routes:

```
resources :squeals do
resources :comments
end
```